# Spring JMS listener connecting to multiple regions

Tags: spring, jms, qpid

I have a listener which listens to a queue name, which is same across regions.
I need to establish connection to multiple regions with different connection urls for the same listener.
could you let me know is it possible using DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.

As of now below code establishes connection to only one region.

```
@Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new BeanFactoryDestinationResolver(springContextBeanFactory));
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        return factory;
    }

@JmsListener(containerFactory = "containerFactory",
        destination = "TestQueue")
public void qpidMessages(String msg){

    System.out.println(msg);

}
```

I need a mechanism to mention List of connections.
I want the configuration to be dynamic based on properties file or read from DB as the connections count differ.

Could you please let me know is there something similar to AbstractRoutingDataSource for JMS Listeners